# local repository on pendrive

Tags: linux, repository

I have a computer at home where I would like to install linux. The problem is that I don't have an Internet connection at home. However, I do have Internet at work but it's on a Windows computer.

Not having a connection to the internet will represent a pain in the a** if I want to install new software, or if I want to update the system (but I am sure you already know that). My idea is to create a mirror repository on a pendrive, so I can download it and keep it up to date using the computer at work and then install whatever I want on the offline computer.

I have two questions about this:

1. How do I create a mirror repository and keep it updated from
   Windows?
2. What pendrive size should I get? 64GB would be enough?

PS. I am planning on installing a Debian based distro.

Comment: Download all the DVDs, install any app from the DVDs, no updates required as you are off the grid. You are complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu there's a nice official guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository).

The ideal way should be using [apt-medium](https://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium) as suggested, but it doesn't seem to work on Windows.

As an alternative, I found [apt-offline](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline), a nice utility written in `python` that looks like is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've followed the guide and  manually downloaded the metioned files but that takes a total of 35Mb?? Where are the rest of the .debs?

I am aware of apt-offline. I think it's quite useful to download a specific package and it's dependencies, but i would like to have it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the security policy at your office, but my be the way to start temporarily your office computer with any Live linux (there is the Debian Live DVD, too) and in such OS you can create the local mirror. Or you can install the small Linux OS into the virtual machine, the VirtualBOX is ported also for MS-Windows. 
If you have the (Debian) Linux already installed at your home PC, you can simply attache the external disk (USB) with the mirror, mount it and add the row into the `/etc/apt/sources.list` with somethink like:

```
deb file:///mnt/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

and test it with `apt-get update`

I cannot judge how big the USB pendrive have to be, but for single arch (amd64) 64GB seems to be enough. You can also try to download the full set of instalation DVD media (at present about 30 DVD) but for the commnoly used package only first 3 is sufficient. In most cases, when the packages to be installed do not request too many deppendencies, you can simply download it from the repository at your office and at home you can install it with:

```
dpkg -i name_of_the_packge
```

but I admit, the local mirror is much more comfortable. 
The nowadays repositories use gpg signature to verify each package, but the gpg key expire in about 3 month, hence after that time you must generate the key again or you may change the row in the `sources.list` to:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:///mnt/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

and/or add the `etc/apt/apt.d/10no_check` with the row:

```
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";
```

As the linux, if installed with "include all modules" request can start on any compatible PC (on contrary to MS-Windows) you can also take the system disk out of your home PC box, put it in your office PC (if allowed) and install everything on-line. Then put it back at home box.

Try what you want.

Comment: Yes. The mirror would be a much more comfortable way of doing it. At least for me. I have a raspberry pi at home. I am going to try and use it to mirror the repository.